# Stored procedure created but not returning output

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I have created a stored procedure - it's created successfully on server but when I am executing it, I get `Procedure Completed` message, but it's not returning any output.

Procedure is below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DFADMIN.USP_GETPICKLIST_DF
(
 P_ORD_TYPE IN varchar2,
 P_PICKLIST_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
 P_PICKLIST_ORD OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
 v_TotalOpenOrder integer;
 v_AstockQty integer;
 v_BstockQty integer;
 v_loopCounter integer;
 v_Astock integer;
 v_Bstock integer;
 v_TotalBStockQty integer;

 BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ORD_NBR) INTO v_TotalOpenOrder  FROM DFADMIN.DF_ORDERS WHERE ORD_STATUS='OPEN' AND ORD_TYPE='DF';
 begin
        if v_TotalOpenOrder>0 then
            v_BstockQty:=round(((v_TotalOpenOrder*60)/100),0);
            v_AstockQty:=v_TotalOpenOrder-v_BstockQty;
             select count(1) into v_Astock  from DFADMIN.Ro_HIST where Process='ASTOCK' AND ORDER_TYPE='DF';
            select count(1) into v_Bstock  from DFADMIN.Ro_HIST where Process='BSTOCK' AND ORDER_TYPE='DF';

            if (v_Bstock < v_BstockQty) then
                open P_PICKLIST_OUT for
                    select T.QTY,T.PUTAWAY_BIN BIN,T.BOXID BOX_ID ,T.PICKQTY PICK_QTY from
                    (
                        Select  sum(I.QTY) QTY, I.PUTAWAY_BIN,I.BOXID,'1' as PickQty
                        from  (select * from DFADMIN.Ro_HIST where ORDER_TYPE='DF' and QTY<=v_Bstock order by created_date asc ) I
                        Where  BOXID in (select K.BOXID from DFADMIN.RO_HIST K)
                        and  I.PROCESS='BSTOCK'  and  I.PUTAWAY_BIN is not null   and QTY<=v_Bstock
                        group by I.PUTAWAY_BIN,I.BOXID,I.QTY, I.PROCESS,'1'
                    union
                        Select  sum(I.QTY) QTY, I.PUTAWAY_BIN,I.BOXID,'1' as PICKQTY
                        from  (select * from DFADMIN.Ro_HIST where  ORDER_TYPE='DF' order by CREATED_DATE asc ) I
                        Where  BOXID in (select K.BOXID from DFADMIN.RO_HIST K )
                        and  I.PROCESS='ASTOCK'  and  I.PUTAWAY_BIN is not null  and QTY<=(v_TotalOpenOrder-v_Bstock) --and case when v_Bstock>0 then  rownum<=(v_TotalOpenOrder-v_Bstock) else rownum>0 end
                        group by I.PUTAWAY_BIN,I.BOXID,I.QTY, I.PROCESS,'1'
                    ) t  order by  T.QTY asc;
                    open P_PICKLIST_ORD for
                    select distinct ORD_NBR,'' QTY,''  BIN,'' BOX_ID ,'' PICK_QTY from  DFADMIN.DF_ORDERS where ORD_STATUS='OPEN' AND ORD_TYPE='DF' ;
                    ELSE 
                    begin
                              open P_PICKLIST_OUT for
                    select T.QTY,T.PUTAWAY_BIN BIN,T.BOXID BOX_ID ,T.PICKQTY PICK_QTY from
                    (
                        Select  sum(I.QTY) QTY, I.PUTAWAY_BIN,I.BOXID,'1' as PickQty
                        from  (select * from DFADMIN.Ro_HIST where ORDER_TYPE='DF' AND QTY<=v_Bstock order by created_date asc ) I
                        Where  BOXID in (select K.BOXID from DFADMIN.RO_HIST K )
                        and  I.PROCESS='BSTOCK'  and  I.PUTAWAY_BIN is not null   and QTY<=v_BstockQty
                        group by I.PUTAWAY_BIN,I.BOXID,I.QTY, I.PROCESS,'1'
                    union
                        Select  sum(I.QTY) QTY, I.PUTAWAY_BIN,I.BOXID,'1' as PICKQTY
                        from  (select * from DFADMIN.Ro_HIST WHERE ORDER_TYPE='DF' order by CREATED_DATE asc ) I
                        Where  BOXID in (select K.BOXID from DFADMIN.RO_HIST K )
                        and  I.PROCESS='ASTOCK'  and  I.PUTAWAY_BIN is not null  and QTY<=(v_TotalOpenOrder-v_BstockQty) --and case when v_Bstock>0 then  rownum<=(v_TotalOpenOrder-v_Bstock) else rownum>0 end
                        group by I.PUTAWAY_BIN,I.BOXID,I.QTY, I.PROCESS,'1'
                    ) t  order by  T.QTY asc;
                    open P_PICKLIST_ORD for
                    select distinct ORD_NBR,'' QTY,''  BIN,'' BOX_ID ,'' PICK_QTY from  DFADMIN.DF_ORDERS where ORD_STATUS='OPEN' AND ORD_TYPE='DF';
                    end ;

            end if;

        end if;

   end;

 END USP_GETPICKLIST_DF;
```

In this procedure there are one input parameter and 2 output parameter.

Comment: How are you executing it? What are you passing in for the two OUT parameters, and how are you trying do display/use the results?

Answer (score 0):

In your procedure, there is no `dbms_output` or anything similar, which would lead to output/display of any data.

There are two output parameters which are of sys_refcursor type, so I suppose
you are considering as your desired output content of these parameters after procedure execution. After the call of the procedure you can fetch these cursors into variables and then e.g. display data like this.

```
declare
vpicklist_out sys_refcursor;
vpicklist_ord sys_refcursor;
myRecord mytable%ROWTYPE;
begin
USP_GETPICKLIST_DF('somestring', vpicklist_out ,vpicklist_ord );
 LOOP
      FETCH vpicklist_out INTO myRecord1;
        EXIT WHEN vpicklist_out%NOTFOUND;
       dbms_output.put_line(to_char(myRecord1.col1));
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Note, that I don't know the exact structure of your data, so myRecord is in my example declared as `ROWTYPE` of some table called mytable.